# Weird behaviour of Material UI Outlined Input React component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, textfield

I want to use material ui outlined input component into my website, but when i have used it into my project by reading mui documentation, the outlined input is not look like actual outlined input. Here is the photo of the outlined input component which i have used in my website.[image]
What is the problem in my code?

```js
import React from 'react';
import { styled, Box, BoxProps, FormControl, OutlinedInput, InputAdornment } from '@mui/material';

import SearchOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/SearchOutlined';

const DesktopSearchBar = styled(Box)<BoxProps>(({ theme }) => ({
    display: "none",
    [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
        display: "flex"
    }
}));

const SearchBar: React.FC = () => {
    return (
        <DesktopSearchBar>
            <FormControl>
                <OutlinedInput
                    placeholder="Search here..."
                    autoComplete="off"
                    endAdornment={
                        <InputAdornment position="start">
                            <SearchOutlinedIcon />
                        </InputAdornment>
                    }
                />
            </FormControl>
        </DesktopSearchBar>
    );
};

export default SearchBar;
```

I have tried using TextField also, but same thing is happening.

Comment: Please help me I don't want to create the Material UI textfield from scratch.

Comment: Issue resolved, the height of fieldset was set to fit-content, which created this problem.